# How to change current directory using the command_not_found_handle in Bash?

Tags: bash

In my .bashrc file, I have a function

```
changeDirectory()
{
 cd "/home/bin"
}
```

If I'm in /home and I type changeDirectory on the command line, the current directory becomes /home/bin

If this function is called from other functions, it also works to change the current directory.

```
handler()
{
 changeDirectory
}
```

If I type handler in the command line, it changes my current directory to /home/bin

However, if I call changeDirectory from this function:

```
command_not_found_handle()
{
 changeDirectory
 echo "$PWD"
}
```

When I type a command this isn't found, and this function is called, it will print /home/bin, but when I type pwd on the command line, I'm still in /home

The command_not_found_handler function seems to behave differently than normal functions. Is there a work around to be able to change my current directory?

Comment: From `man bash`: *If the search is unsuccessful, the shell searches for  a  defined
       shell  function  named command_not_found_handle.  If that function exists, it is invoked in a separate execution environment with the original command and the original command's arguments as its arguments, and the function's exit  status  becomes the exit status of that subshell.* The important part is probably *invoked in a separate execution environment*.

Answer (score 0):

A slight twist on @Cyrus' answer, using a temporary file instead of exit code.

```sh
command_not_found_handle () { touch $HOME/.changedirectory.$$; }
PROMPT_COMMAND='rm $HOME/.changedirectory.$$ 2>/dev/null && changeDirectory'
```